# Add a filename to svn:ignore in case insenstive manner

Tags: svn, svnignore

I want to add a file to a `svn:ignore` so that it is always ignored even if the filename is present in different case. How to do it?

eg:

I want to ignore the file `readme.md`, even if it is present in any case like

```
README.md
readme.MD
Readme.md
......
.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion allows the following [file patterns](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html): `?` (match single character), `*` (match a string of characters) and `[...]` (where ... indicates a subset of characters to match).  As such you can build up your filename using items of the form `[Xx]` for the upper and lower case characters.

Answer (score 4):

```
[Rr][Ee][Aa][Dd][Mm][Ee].[Mm][Dd]
```

Comment: I thought about it. But was wondering if there is a cleaner solution than that.